# How to replace SqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader in .NET Core 2.x?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, f#

I was using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader for async database calls in .NET Framework 4.x as shown here:

```
use! reader = Async.FromBeginEnd(CommandBehavior.SingleRow, 
         (fun (arg,callback,stateObject) -> cmd.BeginExecuteReader(callback,stateObject,arg)), cmd.EndExecuteReader)
```

I'm trying to migrate this code to .NET Core 2.2 and I see that the methods 'BeginExecuteReader' and 'EndExecuteReader' are not available anymore as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netcore-2.2). What can be used from .NET Core 2.2, to provide the same functionality?

Comment: Directly use of ExecuteReaderAsync?

Comment: I'd second `ExecuteReaderAsync`, but otherwise: have you checked .NET Core 3.0 preview? it *might* have resurrected there

Comment: Of interest?! https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/migrating-delegate-begininvoke-calls-for-net-core/

Comment: @Marc, worth a try but since v3.0 is not stable yet, I may not be able to use it for my solution.

Comment: @Selvin, that sounds like a good way to go. Could you provide an example that makes use of a callback and the other variables like my statement above? I'm quite new to F# and that would be really helpful

Comment: I guess `use` is `using` and `!` is `await`... Then `use! reader = cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SingleRow)` should do the thing... but well, I never wrote a code in F#

Comment: @n7rider The async execution method since .NET 4.x is `ExecuteReaderAsync`, not `BeginExecuteReader`. That method was used in previous frameworks that didn't have tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even back in .NET 4.0, the preferred way of executing a command asynchronously was to use one of the `ExecuteXXXAsync` methods that returned a Task. `Begin/End` methods were used in earlier frameworks that didn't have Task.

In F#, [ExecuteReaderAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereaderasync?view=netcore-2.2) can be called in an [asynchronous workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/asynchronous-workflows) :

```
let work = async {
    // Open connection
    use conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    do! conn.OpenAsync() |> Async.AwaitVoidTask

    // Execute command
    use cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText,conn)
    use! reader = cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask

    while reader.Read() do
        // Consume reader
        ...
}
work |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

F# asynchronous workflows were created before .NET 4.0's `Task` type, which is why the `Async.AwaitTask` and `Async.AwaitVoidTask` functions are used to adopt one to the other